# DJI MSDK v4.6.1 Payload SDK example

Tags: dji-sdk

I am having a problem with PSDK v1.2.0 and MSDK v4.6.1.  My M200 and Skyport adapter have been updated to the latest firmware versions but I am still not getting any PSDK messages to the app.  Did something change in how PSDK is registered in the app?  Does anyone have working example code?

TIA

Answer (score 0):

the new sample of MSDK 4.6.1 will be updated very soon.